# Quebra de linha com Onclick JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick

Tenho uma função, que ao clicar altera um elemento, mas também acaba quebrando a linha, já tentei resolver usando o `preventDefault()`, mas sem sucesso.

Quando clicado no ícone `fa-user-secret`, acontece o `onclick` e a quebra de linha

Preciso que ao clicar no ícone, seja altera o conteúdo, e o ícone também, está tudo funcionando, apenas essa quebra de linha ocorre.

```js
// muda tela
var right = document.querySelector("#infoRight").onclick = function() {theRight()};

function theRight() {
    document.querySelector("#infoRight").setAttribute('style', 'display: none;')
    document.querySelector("#infoLeft").setAttribute('style', 'display: block;',)
    document.getElementById("devP").setAttribute('style', 'display: none;')
    document.getElementById("devInfo").setAttribute('style', 'display: block;')
    
}

//volta para home
var left = document.querySelector("#infoLeft").onclick = function() {theLeft()};

function theLeft() {
  document.querySelector("#infoLeft").setAttribute('style', 'display: none;',)
  document.querySelector("#infoRight").setAttribute('style', 'display: block;')
  document.getElementById("devInfo").setAttribute('style', 'display: none;')
  document.getElementById("devP").setAttribute('style', 'display: block;')
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="skillDev" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <p id="iconsHab" class="text-center">
                        <i class="fab fa-js" title="JavaScript"></i>
                        <i class="fab fa-node-js" title="Nodejs"></i>
                        <i class="fab fa-css3-alt" title="CSS3"></i>
                        <i class="fab fa-html5" title="HTML5"></i>
                        <!--Sobre-->
                        <i id="infoRight" class="fas fa-user-secret" title="sobre mim"></i>
                        <i id="infoLeft" class="fas fa-undo-alt" title="voltar"></i>
                        <i class="fab fa-vuejs" title="Vuejs"></i>
                        <i class="fab fa-angular" title="Angular"></i>
                        <i class="fab fa-react" title="Reactjs"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-coffee" title="Muito Café!! Muito Mesmo"></i>
                    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Resolvido, alterei a propriedade para `display: inline-block`, a propriedade `display: block`não permite setar altura e larguras.

Answer (score 0):

Voce esta usando o

```
document.querySelector("#infoRight").setAttribute('style', 'display: block;')
```

display block faz com que quebre a linha.

Voce trocar para display inline

```
 document.querySelector("#infoRight").setAttribute('style', 'display : inline;')
```

Comment: Não funciona, já havia tentado, pois ao clicar no ícone, deve ocultar uma `div` e trocar o ícone.

Comment: Nao esta muito bem explicado o que voce precisa. O que realmente voce quer fazer? voce quer trocar o icone? usa jQuery?

Comment: Quero apenas que não aconteça essa quebra de linha, toda a minha lógica já funciona, apenas este detalhes.
o `hidden` e o `visible`apenas escondem, o conteúdo, mas a `div`continua ali, ocupando o espaço delimitado.
Não se se existe uma forma de prevenir a quebra de linha do `display:block`.

Comment: Mas qual `div`? no seu exemplo as imagens (tag `<i>`) estão todas soltas soltas de um parágrafo, não há `div` ali, nem no seu código `javascript`, precisa explicar melhor isso

Comment: Editei a resposta, acredito que seja isso que voce quer